# How to change upper execution time limit for a DBpedia SPARQL query? (Virtuoso 42000 error)

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am querying DBpedia using SPARQL through Python. I am facing issues with the upper execution time limit. This is the error :

Code :

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
newquery = "DEFINE input:inference "skos-trans" PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
select distinct ?cat1 ?cat2 ?cat3 ?cat4  where { 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pulp_Fiction> dcterms:subject ?cat1 . 
?cat1  skos:broaderTransitive   ?cat2. 
?cat2  skos:broaderTransitive   ?cat3. 
?cat3  skos:broaderTransitive   ?cat4. 
 } "

sparql.setQuery( newquery)
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
```

Response:
`Virtuoso 42000 Error The estimated execution time 5286 (sec) exceeds the limit of 3000 (sec)`

How to get through this problem ??

Answer (score 1):

You can't using the public DBPedia endpoint, because the endpoint is very well known it is also heavily used so they have to limit how complex a query they allow people to run.

If you need to run queries that run into issues like this timeout consider using one of the available [database dumps](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38) and running them in a local copy of Virtuoso or a triple store of your choice.