# Querying DBPedia using SPARQL to find subjects with same objects

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am trying to find all those resources from dbpedia for eg rdf:type person who have same object eg date of birth.?
I thought of doing it with subquery but its definitely not the solution.
Can anyone provide some useful pointer?

Comment: How should the result look like? For each birthdate all persons? Or `birthdate, person1, person2`? Show the SPARQL query that you tried so far.

Comment: The result would be something like this 
person 1, person2, DateofBirth.
abc             bcd        12/12/2001
wer             erw        14/10/2001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe I think you mean:

```
prefix dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

select ?s1 ?s2 ?dob
where {
    ?s1 a foaf:Person ; dbp:birthDate ?dob . # Find a person, get their dob
    ?s2 a foaf:Person ; dbp:birthDate ?dob . # Find a person with the same dob
}
```

Adjust type and predicate to suit.

This will include some redundancy: you will find answers where the subjects are the same ('Napoleon' 'Napoleon') and get answers twice ('Daniel Dennett' 'Neil Kinnock', 'Neil Kinnock' 'Daniel Dennett'). You can remove that with a filter:

```
filter (?s1 < ?s2)
```

which just ensures that one comes before the other (however the query engine wants to do that).

```
prefix dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

select ?s1 ?s2 ?dob
where {
    ?s1 a foaf:Person ; dbp:birthDate ?dob .
    ?s2 a foaf:Person ; dbp:birthDate ?dob .
    filter (?s1 < ?s2)
}
```

[See the result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix+dbp%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0Aprefix+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect+%3Fs1+%3Fs2+%3Fdob%0D%0Awhere+%7B%0D%0A%3Fs1+a+foaf%3APerson+%3B+dbp%3AbirthDate+%3Fdob+.%0D%0A%3Fs2+a+foaf%3APerson+%3B+dbp%3AbirthDate+%3Fdob+.%0D%0Afilter+%28%3Fs1+%3C+%3Fs2%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Thank you user205512 for the valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

A SPARQL query is basically a set of triple patterns, i.e., a join (logical AND) of queries of the form

```
?subject ?predicate ?object.
```

What you need is identical `?object`. Considering that you only care about `?subject` (`?predicate` is not of importance), you can perform such a query you by ordering the results depending on `?object`. Thus you will see results sharing `?object` together.

```
select ?s ?p ?o where {

    ?s ?p ?o.        
}
order by ?o
```

If you care about `?predicate` as well, you should order the result using it second.

```
select ?s ?p ?o where {

    ?s ?p ?o.        
}
order by ?o ?p
```

As those couple of queries may involve too many results as they will retrieve all the results possible. I recommend filtering `?object` depending on some specific criteria. For example, to select all `?subject` sharing an instance of `Person` as their `?object`, use:

```
select ?s where {

?s ?p ?o.
{select  ?o where{
    ?o a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>}
}
}
```

Comment: Odes this really answer the question? If would more expect queries that result in `object, subject1, subject2` or even `object, subject_1, ..., subject_n`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to the others is using aggregate functions like in this query template

```sql
select ?o (count(distinct ?s) as ?cnt) (group_concat(distinct ?s; separator=";") as ?subjects) {
?s a <CLASS> ;
   <PREDICATE> ?o .
}
group by ?o
order by desc(count(distinct ?s))
```

which returns for each object the number of subjects and the list of subject belonging to a class `CLASS` for a given predicate `PREDICATE`

For example, asking for the dates of soccer players one could use

```sql
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select ?date (count(distinct ?s) as ?cnt) (group_concat(distinct ?s; separator=";") as ?subjects) {
?s a dbo:SoccerPlayer ;
   dbo:birthDate ?date .
}
group by ?date
order by desc(count(distinct ?s))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * where {
?person1 a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>.
?person1 dbo:birthYear ?date.
?person2 a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>.
?person2 dbo:birthYear ?date


FILTER (?person1 != ?person2)
}
limit 10
```

Dbpedia will not allow you to execute that query on its public endpoint because it consumes more time that allowed, and [you cannot change that time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967785/how-to-change-upper-execution-time-limit-for-a-dbpedia-sparql-query-virtuoso-4). Nevertheless, [there are ways to execute it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33079526/virtuoso-42000-error-when-using-dbpedia-sparql)